# Cambiar el nombre de clase en etiquetas li usando javscript o jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hola amigos estoy tratando cambiar la el nombre de la clase de 2 < li>

ambas etiquetas contienen el mismo nombre de la clase **give-icon give-icon-question** necesito remover **give-icon-question** y agregar  **fas fa-credit-card** a un  **li** y al otro **fas fa-credit-card**

con esta idea deberia quedar asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
el número de asignación es 4 y 5 ya que el formulario contiene otros input

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('give-icon', 'give-icon-question')[4].classList;
element.remove('give-icon', 'give-icon-question');
element.add('fas', 'fa-credit-card');

var element1 = document.getElementsByClassName('give-icon', 'give-icon-question')[5].classList;
element1.remove('give-icon', 'give-icon-question');
element1.add('fas', 'fa-calendar');
```

```html
<fieldset id="give-ffm-section" data-fields="numero_de_tarjeta|vencimiento">

    <div id="numero_de_tarjeta-wrap">       
        <input class="textfield required" id="ffm-numero_de_tarjeta" type="text" data-required="yes" data-type="text" required="required" name="numero_de_tarjeta" placeholder="Tarjeta: xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx" value="0000 0000 0000 0000" maxlength="19" tabindex="1">  
        <div class="give-tooltip-wrap">
        <span class="give-tooltip hint--top" data-tooltip="n.º de tarjeta: xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx" aria-label="n.º de tarjeta: xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx">
        <i class="**give-icon give-icon-question**"></i>
        </span>
        </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="vencimiento-wrap">     
        <input id="ffm-vencimiento" type="text" data-dateformat="mm/yy" data-timeformat="h:mm tt" class="give-ffm-date give-ffm-timepicker give-ffm-datepicker-vencimiento" data-required="yes" data-type="text" required="required" placeholder="Vencimiento" name="vencimiento" value="" size="30" tabindex="1">
        <div class="give-tooltip-wrap">
        <span class="give-tooltip hint--top" data-tooltip="2/2023" aria-label="2/2023">
        <i class="**give-icon give-icon-question**"></i>
        </span>
        </div>
        </div>
</fieldset>
```

cuando ejecuto en la consola del navegador

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('give-icon', 'give-icon-question')[4].classList;
element.remove('give-icon', 'give-icon-question');
element.add('fas', 'fa-credit-card');
```

realiza el proceso, pero cuando agrego el fragmento directamente en el archivo del formulario no funciona correctamente

Answer (score 0):

Intente de la siguiente forma realiza el cambio desde la consola, recorre la pagina con un for en busca de la clase **give-icon-question** , cuando agrego directamente el codigo el en archivo del formulario no se ejecuta como debería

```js
var fas = document.getElementsByClassName("give-icon-question");
for (var i = 0; i<fas.length; i++) {
   fas[i].classList.remove("give-icon-question");
   fas[i].classList.add('fas','fa-credit-card');
}
```

```html
<span class="give-tooltip hint--top" data-tooltip="n.º de tarjeta: xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx" aria-label="n.º de tarjeta: xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx">
<i class="give-icon give-icon-question"></i>
</span>
```